Bijection between bounded module maps from $\ell^2(\mathfrak{U})$ to $\mathfrak{U}$ and set of sequences with a property
In Self-Duality and $C^*$-Reflexivity of Hilbert $C^*$-Moduli (1990) by M. Frank, there is the following lemma:

Lemma 4.1: Let $\mathfrak{U}$ be a $C^*$-algebra with identity and $\ell^2(\mathfrak{U})$ be the standard countably generated Hilbert $C^*$-module. Then the map $\psi: f \in \ell^2(\mathfrak{U})' \to \{f(e_i)^*\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a bijection between
$\ell^2(\mathfrak{U})'$ and the set of all sequences $\mathbf{a} = \{a_i \}_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathfrak{U}$ with the property $\sup_N || a_1 a_1^* + \ldots + a_N a_N^*|| < \infty$. Moreover, $\psi$ maps all bounded module maps of the form $\phi(\mathbf{a}) =  \langle \cdot, \mathbf{a}\rangle, \mathbf{a} \in \ell^2 (\mathfrak{U})$, into the characterizing element $\mathbf{a}$ and vice versa.

Where $\ell^2(\mathfrak{U})'$ is the set of all bounded module maps $f:\ell^2(\mathfrak{U}) \to \mathfrak{U}$. The paper provides other papers where this lemma is mentioned (without proof) and says it's easy to prove, but I don't find that to be the case. The property clearly holds for maps of the form $\phi(\mathbf{a})$, but what about the other maps? Here's a sketch of an attempt:
Let $u_i= f(e_i)^* \in \mathfrak{U}$. Then
\begin{align}
|| f(e_1)f(e_1)^* + \ldots + f(e_N) f(e_N)^*||_\mathfrak{U} 
&= || f(e_1 u_1^*) + \ldots + f(e_N u_N^*)||_\mathfrak{U} \\
&= || f(e_1 u_1^* + \ldots + e_N u_N^* )||_\mathfrak{U}\\
&\leq c \cdot ||e_1 u_1^* + \ldots + e_N u_N^* ||_{\ell^2(\mathfrak{U})'}
\end{align}
But why would $||e_1 u_1^* + \ldots + e_N u_N^* ||_{\ell^2(\mathfrak{U})'}$ itself be bounded?

Just to check, are Hilbert $C^\ast$-modules here supposed to have $A$ acting on the right, but the inner products are linear in the first variable? (So in particular, on $\ell^2(A)$, $\langle (a_n), (b_n) \rangle = \sum_n b_n^\ast a_n$?) And $\ell^2(A)$ consists of all sequences $(a_n)$ s.t. $\sum_n |a_n|^2 < \infty$?

Oh wait, given the way this is written down, maybe $A$ is supposed to act on the left and $\langle (a_n), (b_n) \rangle = \sum_n a_nb_n^\ast$ on $\ell^2(A)$ instead?

Hello! They are considered left modules with the inner product being linear in the first variable. I've added the reference in the question. It also confuses me a bit, I may have used it the wrong way at my sketch...

I see. I don’t have time right now, but I’ll write an answer later.

Here is a full answer, as promised:
To start with, we show that the sequence $a_i = f(e_i)^\ast$ does satisfy $\sup_N \|a_1a_1^\ast + \cdots + a_Na_N^\ast\| < \infty$. Indeed, consider $\xi = \sum_{i=1}^N a_ie_i \in \ell^2(A)$. Then,
$$\|\xi\|^2 = \|\sum_{i=1}^N a_ia_i^\ast\|$$
Thus,
$$\begin{split}
\|\sum_{i=1}^N a_ia_i^\ast\|^2 &= \|\sum_{i=1}^N a_if(e_i)\|^2\\
&= \|f(\xi)\|^2\\
&\leq \|f\|^2\|\xi\|^2\\
&= \|f\|^2\|\sum_{i=1}^N a_ia_i^\ast\|
\end{split}$$
Therefore, $\|\sum_{i=1}^N a_ia_i^\ast\| \leq \|f\|^2$. Whence,
$$\sup_N \|a_1a_1^\ast + \cdots + a_Na_N^\ast\| \leq \|f\|^2 < \infty$$
We also observe that the sequence $a_i = f(e_i)^\ast$ uniquely determines $f$, i.e., the map $f \mapsto (a_i)$ is injective. For this, let $c_{00}(A) \subset \ell^2(A)$ consists of finitely supported sequences. Then for any $\sum_{i=1}^N b_ie_i \in c_{00}(A)$, we have,
$$f(\sum_{i=1}^N b_ie_i) = \sum_{i=1}^N b_if(e_i) = \sum_{i=1}^N b_ia_i^\ast$$
So $(a_i)$ uniquely determines the behavior of $f$ on $c_{00}(A)$. Since the latter is dense in $\ell^2(A)$, this proves the result.
Now, for surjectivity, we need to show, for any sequence $(a_i)$ s.t. $C = \sup_N \|a_1a_1^\ast + \cdots + a_Na_N^\ast\| < \infty$, the map $f: \ell^2(A) \to A$,
$$f((b_i)) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty b_ia_i^\ast$$
is a well-defined, bounded, module map. We first need to show the infinite sum above converges. Indeed, as $(b_i) \in \ell^2(A)$, and as the latter space is the completion of $c_{00}(A)$, we have,
$$\sum_{i=1}^k b_ie_i \to (b_i) \text{ in }\ell^2(A)\text{, as }k \to \infty$$
Hence,
$$\|\sum_{i=m}^n b_ie_i\|^2 = \|\sum_{i=m}^n b_ib_i^\ast\| \to 0\text{, as }m, n \to \infty$$
So by Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$\begin{split}
\|\sum_{i=m}^n b_ia_i^\ast\| &\leq \|\sum_{i=m}^n b_ib_i^\ast\|^{1/2}\|\sum_{i=m}^n a_ia_i^\ast\|^{1/2}\\
&\leq \|\sum_{i=m}^n b_ib_i^\ast\|^{1/2}\|\sum_{i=1}^n a_ia_i^\ast\|^{1/2}\\
&\leq C^{1/2}\|\sum_{i=m}^n b_ib_i^\ast\|^{1/2}\\
&\to 0
\end{split}$$
Thus, the partial sum sequence is Cauchy, so the infinite sum converges. Similar arguments show that $f$ is bounded with $\|f\| \leq C^{1/2}$. That $f$ is a module map is easy to see from the definition.
